# How to reslove "AttributeError for plotting' error while importing folium

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, folium

I have install pandas, numpy, folium.
While importing folium I am getting below error.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import folium
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\folium\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from branca.colormap import (ColorMap, LinearColormap, StepColormap)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\branca\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import branca.colormap as colormap
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\branca\colormap.py", line 14, in <module>
    from branca.element import ENV, Figure, JavascriptLink, MacroElement
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utilities import _camelify, _parse_size, none_min, none_max
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\branca\utilities.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    plot_params = pandas.plotting._style._Options(deprecated=True)
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'`

I tried searching online and got one answer that upgrading pandas will resolve this issue but when I tried to upgrade pandas I got message as "Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade:"

Comment: Getting error even while importing pandas, `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    plot_params = pandas.plotting._style._Options(deprecated=True)
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'`

Answer (score 0):

I tried upgrading pandas as got suggestion from one of link on stackoverflow.

Atlast I restarted my system and it work this time, without any issue.